# Exporting MSCharts to PPT files using  ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

How would I export MSCharts to `.ppt` using ASP.NET/C#?.

I am creating mscharts dynamically which I need to export to `.ppt`. I am able to export to `.pdf` using itextxharp, but no luck with `.ppt`.

Can anyone tell me the way to export or do we have any third party DLL to do so?

Comment: How do you create the charts, or with what component? It is not really clear. I think you have to use the Office Interop API. Take a look at this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733.aspx

Comment: There is a chart control available in .Net 4.0. add reference  System.Web.DataVisualization to have chart control

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to embed in PPT document.

For embedding images into word document you can see http://docx.codeplex.com/

This will give some idea. Not sure is any other library for PPT.

Answer (score 0):

try converting the mscharts to images and then add those images to ppt file using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint` dll.